Faith and Evidence: Two Types of Trust?
The Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy defines faith as:

Faith is a trusting commitment to someone or something. Faith helps us meet our goals, keeps our relationships secure, and enables us to retain our commitments over time. Faith is thus a central part of a flourishing life.

Faith and evidence are usually treated as opposing grounds for belief (that is, a man of religion might treat faith as justifying his religious beliefs, etc.). Yet, most of us are not scientists with access to all the equipment and raw data of high-end scientific experiments. Yes of course, scientists are hopefully grounding their claims in evidence (or the lack thereof), but in the end none of us know this for certain.
The IEP also goes on to say:

This subsection discusses four key features of faith: trust, risk, resilience, and going beyond the evidence. These four features are often associated with faith. They are not necessarily synonymous with faith, and not all accounts of faith give all four a starring role.

Nonetheless, they play a role in understanding faith and its effects.
My question is, aren't we all running around justifying our beliefs on some basis of trust in a person or community of persons? While one can argue trust in religious authorities is more problematic than trust in the scientific community (be it peer review or the fact that there are "no sacred cows" for scientists), is it not the case that both faith and evidence (or faith and reason) are at the end of the day, a type of trust in a community's efforts?
Would be very interested to hear of philosophers that speak of epistemological projects as rooted in communities or trust in said communities (in contrast to the "lone genius" doing everything in his armchair).

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This is a point religiously inclined people often attempt to make, and has been put forth by some philosophers. They claim that faith in God is like faith in scientific evidence and testimony, but I suspect it's a much more popular belief that confusing faith in God and the trust we put in the scientific community (as an example) is an informal fallacy called an equivocation because there are two senses to the word faith. Consider MW's definitions of faith:

a (1) : belief and trust in and loyalty to God
[a] (2) : belief in the traditional doctrines of a religion
b (1) : firm belief in something for which there is no proof

Belief and trust in God is FAITHA in MW's definition (a) as covered by the article Faith (SEP), whereas belief in science is often rationally coherent and based on peer-reviewed empirical evidence which might better be called  knowledge because the standards of truth and justification are far more rigorous and consistent by the standards of physicalism. In this sense scientific knowledge, even if taken on personal FAITHB in the testimony, is not to be taken as that the knowledge acquired by science and scientists is per se without rational and empirical proof. So, a small child might have FAITHB in the words of her science teacher, but that is qualitatively different than FAITHA as practiced and advocated by theologians and fideists. From the SEP article, section 11 on Faith:

Can there be faith of the same general kind as found in theistic religious faith yet without adherence to any theistic tradition? Those who agree with F. R. Tennant that ‘faith is an outcome of the inborn propensity to self-conservation and self-betterment which is a part of human nature, and is no more a miraculously superadded endowment than is sensation or understanding’ (1943 [1989, 111]) will consider that this must be a possibility. Tennant himself suggests that ‘much of the belief which underlies knowledge’—and he has scientific knowledge in mind—‘is the outcome of faith which ventures beyond the apprehension and treatment of data to supposition, imagination and creation of ideal objects, and justifies its audacity and irrationality (in accounting them to be also real) by practical actualization’ (1943 [1989, 100]). Faith in this sense, however, may not seem quite on a par with faith of the religious kind. True, scientists must act as if their ‘ideal objects’ are real in putting their theories to the empirical test; but they will ‘account them to be also real’ only when these tests do provide confirmation in accordance with the applicable inter-subjective norms. (emphasis mine)

It's this last part that prima facie seems to set apart theistic faith from the credibility to consider scientific belief actual knowledge. Whereas religious traditions, my own included, tend to make arguments that are highly rhetorical and quite persuasive to many in nature, they inevitably lack the rigor and the inter-subjective methods and theories of the latter. Almost no one in science, for instance, disputes Einstein's papers, at this point, but among Christians, even the act of picking a single version of the Bible would be just about impossible to imagine. And that doesn't include interpretations, such as the august Book of Concord which purports to be the only, true interpretation of the Bible (to the chagrin of my Catholic forbears).
So, there is something fundamentally different between theistic faith and simply trusting in the secular sciences, be they formal, natural, or social, in regards to how methodologically they generate knowledge. And according to Gould, one needn't even see the two methods of trusting in something beyond one's personal ken, as at odds, as he argues in his claims about NOMA. One simply has to accept that trust in science and scientists has more to do with their success in predicting and producing in the physical world. In that case, it would be possible to simply point out that science has proven so successful (can't pray rockets into orbit or cure disease with benediction!) that every act of a theist adopting methodological naturalism is itself a form of proof that science (whatever your views on demarcation) works.

+1, although I very much like Annika's answer, I think you do a good job of showing how "faith" in the scientific community is pretty different from religious faith. For example, I haven't a clue how a car engine operates, I have "faith" in car mechanics, but that faith has empirical results (and can be easily broken if I'm ripped off, etc.).

Most religious people would not agree with (if not be outright offended) at the presumption their faith is "blind" -- i.e., faith for no reason. Ask any believer why they believe an you'll rarely hear "Because I just believe", there will be reasons. For example, Christians may cite Paul's admonition that salvation comes from faith in Jesus as the savior, not from works. Hence, you'd nurture a healthy faith due to this.
@David Gudeman mentioned in the comments the importance of "testimony". I think that testimony serves as a common source of trust for both faith and science.
So it's not that faith and science are categorically different, they just place trust in different groups, books, people etc.

For this question, the notion of testimony that seems the most relevant is Authoritative Testimony, which is underwritten by principles of epistemic authority. An abstract from OUP nicely summarizes epistemic authority:

The basic idea is that epistemic authority is justified by my conscientious judgment that I am more likely to form a true belief (or a belief that will satisfy conscientious self-reflection) if I believe what the authority believes than if I try to figure out what to believe myself. This principle shows that the value of getting the truth can conflict with the value of self-reliance. 1

Therefore, under the framework of epistemic authority there really is no difference between the believer trusting their pastor on  matters of religion and anyone (including said believer) trusting an ornithologist's on matters pertaining to birds. In both cases, we assess that we are more likely to be correct by trusting their views than relying on our own (often inferior) knowledge -- unless of course I have evidence that appears to contradict them, in which case I'd likely ask them to respond to it vs dismiss them as authorities out of hand.
1 Zagzebski, Linda Trinkaus, '5 Trust and Epistemic Authority', Epistemic Authority: A Theory of Trust, Authority, and Autonomy in Belief (2012; online edn, Oxford Academic, 24 Jan. 2013), https://doi.org/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199936472.003.0006, accessed 16 Dec. 2024.

+1, seems a pretty reasonable take on the matter. I'll wait and see for other potential answers, but if no others appear this is a decent response. No follow-up questions from me!

Of course religious people would deny that: they have to. Why would anyone admit to believing in something without evidence? Reports of miracles which are ultimately just words on a paper written many, many years after a purported divine like human being’s death is not evidence.

@Syed my sense is the OP is not interested in the justifiability of faith but in the nature of the epistemological relationship between the listener and provider of testimony. In both cases, I'm arguing they are similar in kind, but to your point, perhaps not in degree.

I believe the book by Zagzebski that you cite points out both similarities and differences between moral and religious authority on one side and scientific authorities on the other.

@tkruse I’d imagine there are — just like mathematics would also be different. I just don’t think it’s Trust that is different

The question of types of trust in the context of faith and evidence is a central theme in biblical philosophy. By examining the relationships between faith, trust and evidence, we can draw on philosophical arguments as well as scripture to clarify this distinction.
Two types of trust
1.Rational (or evidence-based) trust:

This form of trust is based on tangible, rational evidence. From this perspective, faith can be seen as a conviction that generally emerges from a critical and heuristic evaluation of the available evidence.
Biblical example: In the Gospel of John 20:24-29, Thomas doubts Jesus' resurrection until he sees the evidence of the resurrection (Jesus' wounds). Jesus then says to him, "Because you have seen me, you have believed; blessed are those who have not seen and have believed." This suggests that faith can exist independently of visible evidence, but also that there is trust built on experience and observation.

2.Faithful trust (or faith):

This form of trust is much more abstract and involves a personal commitment to a reality or truth, often beyond visible or tangible evidence. It concerns trust in God and His promises, even in the absence of direct empirical evidence.
-Biblical example: In Hebrews 11:1, it says: "Now faith is the firm assurance of things hoped for, the demonstration of things not seen." This reflects a confidence that doesn't depend on the material world, but on a relationship with the divine.

Philosophical arguments
1.The notion of faith as an ultimate value:

According to Christian philosophy, faith transcends mere rationality and evidence. Thinkers like Saint Augustine emphasized the idea that faith is a prerequisite for understanding ("credo ut intelligam" - I believe in order to understand). This shows that faith opens the way to a deeper understanding of divine reality.

2.The challenge of the infinite:

In his reflection on God, Blaise Pascal pointed out that certain divine truths transcend our capacity for rational understanding. Thus, trust in God must sometimes transcend the material evidence we have. Yielding to a faith that accepts that any ultimate understanding of God is beyond our human capacity is a profound act of trust.

Conclusion
In conclusion, the distinction between faith and evidence represents two types of trust that coexist and complement each other in the spiritual life. Trust based on evidence can consolidate our faith, but faith itself, as a form of faithful trust, often transcends that evidence and calls us to a deeper commitment to divine truth. Scripture and Christian philosophy remind us that faith, while it can be strengthened by rational elements, is not solely conditioned by them. It is a spiritual journey that requires both reason and surrender.

This reads like ChatGPT

@Annika Well, it is a good faith effort to comport to the criticisms of the theological response previously offered. ; ) Moving in the right direction, in other words.

+1 "According to Christian philosophy, faith transcends mere rationality and evidence." This is an important philosophical point, one that fideism adopts with a full heart! You'll get the hang of it if you hang around. Good luck!

It scores 27% AI, 73% human, so we should give it the benefit of the doubt.

I have a question: can I use ChatGpt as long as it helps me provide certain parts of the answer to questions, or is it simply forbidden? Greetings to everyone. Shalom!


is it not the case that both faith and evidence (or faith and reason) are at the end of the day, a type of trust in a community's efforts?

In psychology, that may be true of most people, yes. But since the question is about philosophy, in philosophy the answer is different. Western philosophy is based on dialectic processes as basis of trust, rather than mere bearers of authority. This typically is presentes as the heritage of Sokrates and Plato. This makes philosophy in general a search for truth no matter what any authority says.
Examples for dialectic processes:

Votes and regular elections in Multi-Party systems un democracy
Separation of powers in the government
Free and independent judges
A free and independent press
A market without monopolies with pressure from competitors
Peer reviews in science publications, requirements of evidence and falsifiability

The very same people and communities involved in all of those should not be trusted if those processes were not in place.
You should not trust a government that controls the media and courts (like in Nazi Germany).
You should not trust a manufacturer of car seats for toddlers unless they face severe punishment by law if they sell seats without proper testing. You should not trust airplane manufacturers unless they face bad business numbers should their 737Max crash multiple times due to sensor failures.
All these systems of checks and balances is what makes those authorities trustworthy in the first place, not their kind and noble attitude.
And that does not hold for religion and morality, where no such systems of checks and balances exist, and any person can become a guru as long as they find enough gullible followers using one trick or another.

Yes, they are both types of trust, for obvious reasons. You can almost never directly observe the results of scientific experiments the same way you can’t directly observe the purported miracles that many religious people testify to, unless you are a witness yourself.
However, one cannot ignore the difference in claims being made here. The more extraordinary the claim, the greater the evidence required, because a miraculous claim directly goes against centuries of scientific knowledge that humans collectively have verified the truth of through firsthand day to day experience, experiments, testimony, and other kinds of evidence.
